# Numbering sheets (not pages) in MS Word or LibreOffice

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice, word-processing, abiword

I work at a Brazilian government office.  Our paper processes, which are due to retirement in favour of an eletronic one but just not yet®, require us to number sheets, not pages.  So pages 1, 2, 3, 4… become sheets 1, 1v, 2, 2v… (a sheet and its back side, which would be usually page 2, 4… but we call the back of sheets 1v, 2v…)

I can try to insert a simple page number, trying to make it start from 2 and then putting it inside a mathematical funcion dividing by two, but besides I being almost sure I will hit some horrible snag, I would rather use a more straightforward, support method if possible.

Not to mention since processes are always constituted of several files, which we add one at a time and always at the end, we need to be able to start at any given number.  But I guess that is the least of my worries.

Can LibreOffice or MS Word do this?  Perhaps OpenOffice.org?  Or any other reasonable word processor?

**UPDATE:**
OK, I am convinced I need to use functions to halve the number of the page, starting at a convenient number.

I did this in MS Word, with `{={PAGE}/2}`.  Now, I neither found a way of doing the same in LibreOffice, nor converting the MS Word document worked.  I can live with that, but if someone knew if it is really not supported in a free software text processor, or if there is a timeline for such a support in LibreOffice, OpenOffice.org or whatever… I would be grateful.

Thank you all.

Comment: As far as Word is concerned, you can create page numbers like this using a calculation, but you will hit horrible snags when, for example, you insert a table of contents field that references page numbers: it will use the value that { page } would insert, not the calculated value.

Comment: It is just these snags I would like to avoid, but this particular one would not trouble us we do not really use such functionality.  Each document forming a process tends to be short and simple, with usually no more than six or seven pages, usually one to five.

Comment: Well, you could try the nested field { =MOD({ PAGE },2) \#"'{ =({ PAGE }+1)/2 }';;'{ ={ PAGE }/2 }v'" }. All the {} are the special field code brace that you can insert using ctrl-F9. You may need to use the list separator defined in your Regional Settings instead of the ","

Comment: I no not need to print the back numbers suffixed by v, so actually it is much simpler: {={PAGE}/2} only at front pages, with {PAGE} starting at double the sheet number.  It is just that it strikes me as fragile, so I would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: > simpler. Understood. But I don't see an even simpler way, only other ways that also involve a nested { PAGE } field. FWIW I do not see how you do calculations on the page number field in LibreOffice, because there seems to be no facility to nest fields as in Word. But I don't know LibreOffice well. You can create a table and put the page number in cell A1, then use a formula (=<A1>/2 ) in cell B1. But if you do that in a header, the formula result is (the highest page number in the document)/2, unlike in Word.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is it; nested fields in MS Word, no alternative in free software (yet).

As no one answered, should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in MS Word, with `{={PAGE}/2}`. Now, I neither found a way of doing the same in LibreOffice, nor converting the MS Word document worked. I can live with that, but if someone knew if it is really not supported in a free software text processor, or if there is a timeline for such a support in LibreOffice, OpenOffice.org or whatever… I would be grateful.